# THREE.JS Exporting JSON models from blender (including textures)

Tags: javascript, json, export, three.js, blender

I'm using the mrdoob Blender Export Plugin (io_mesh_threejs) to Export to Three JS, but the exported .js or .dae objects do not contain any reference to the texture map files. Is there a special way I need to export the object? Alternatively, is there a special way I need to apply the map to the object in Blender 2.65 in order for the exporter to include it. Lastly, if there is not a way, can I manually add the texture in the JS file?

---

***Blender Before Export***

[image]

---

***JSON Object Exported (without reference to texture)***

```
{

    "metadata" :
    {
        "formatVersion" : 3.1,
        "generatedBy"   : "Blender 2.65 Exporter",
        "vertices"      : 8,
        "faces"         : 6,
        "normals"       : 8,
        "colors"        : 0,
        "uvs"           : [4],
        "materials"     : 1,
        "morphTargets"  : 0,
        "bones"         : 0
    },

    "scale" : 1.000000,

    "materials" : [ {
        "DbgColor" : 15658734,
        "DbgIndex" : 0,
        "DbgName" : "Material",
        "blending" : "NormalBlending",
        "colorAmbient" : [0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865],
        "colorDiffuse" : [0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865],
        "colorSpecular" : [0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
        "depthTest" : true,
        "depthWrite" : true,
        "shading" : "Lambert",
        "specularCoef" : 50,
        "transparency" : 1.0,
        "transparent" : false,
        "vertexColors" : false
    }],

    "vertices" : [1,-0.988938,-1,1,-0.988938,1,-1,-0.988938,1,-1,-0.988938,-1,1,1.01106,-0.999999,0.999999,1.01106,1,-1,1.01106,1,-1,1.01106,-1],

    "morphTargets" : [],

    "normals" : [0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,0.577349],

    "colors" : [],

    "uvs" : [[1,-0,1,1,0,1,-0,0]],

    "faces" : [43,0,1,2,3,0,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,43,4,7,6,5,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,43,0,4,5,1,0,0,1,2,3,0,4,7,1,43,1,5,6,2,0,0,1,2,3,1,7,6,2,43,2,6,7,3,0,0,1,2,3,2,6,5,3,43,4,0,3,7,0,2,3,0,1,4,0,3,5],

    "bones" : [],

    "skinIndices" : [],

    "skinWeights" : [],

    "animation" : {}


}
```

---

***Code To Load JSON Object***

```
var object;
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();          

loader.load( "./quirk_logo.js", function(geometry, materials) {
     var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
     object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials);

     object.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
     scene.add(object)
     render();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can first export your model to `.obj` from your Blender and then follow the rest part of this tutorial to get your right `.json` model.
http://bkcore.com/blog/3d/webgl-three-js-workflow-tips.html

Comment: I would like to run the script without installing Python

Comment: If you do not want to install Python, you should try its portable version (I'm using this version). [Download page](http://portablepython.com/wiki/PortablePython2.7.5.1)

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you are looking for.

http://graphic-sim.com/B_basic_export.html

Comment: It might be to do with your loader code I was comparing it with mine and I have this:

var modelLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader().load( "./quirk_logo.js", function ( geometry, materials ) {
 var material = materials[ 0 ];
 var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ) );
  
 mesh.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
 scene.add( mesh );
} );

My only guess is you aren't setting your materials array to the first element so it's creating the mesh but not applying the material if you have followed the above tutorial. If it still doesn't work after that I'll try help some more.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the example i cooked up .

https://github.com/master-atul/blender3js

U can see the working example here :

http://www.atulr.com/blender3js

You can check out my code from my repo link.

And if you wish to know the export options i used :

I directly exported the animations and everything from blender with options described here.

https://devmatrix.wordpress.com/2013/02/27/creating-skeletal-animation-in-blender-and-exporting-it-to-three-js/

Hope this helps 
Cheers :)

Comment: What does this have to do with textures?  His question was about exporting models with textures.